# Rename files generated during webGL build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just loaded up a Unity WebGL project that I downloaded from github.

When I build it, all the build files in the `obj` folder are named like `obj.framework.js, obj.data` etc...

Is there a way to change `obj` to something like `galaxyEducation.framework.js, galaxyEducation.data` etc...?

I looked in `Project Settings` section of Unity, but couldn't find anything.

Is there a place to set this?

Thanks!

Comment: Files in the obj folder are not the final files. Who cares what they are called?

Comment: @BugFinder Oh ok, thanks, I'm new to Unity.  Where are the final files located?  When I built the project, they went into the 'obj' folder.  Thank you.

Comment: Wherever you told it to put them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else asks, I found this answer:

> The Build folder contains the following files ([ExampleBuild]
> represents the name of the target build folder)

On this Unity website: [Building and running a WebGL project](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/webgl-building.html)